# Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database

Tags: sql, database, derby

I'm connecting to a Derby DB through the command line. After connecting, by mistake got out from IJ in a unproper way. Now when I try to connect again this message is shown:

[image]

I think this is happening because i didn't close the connection properly. So I made both "disconnect all;" and "disconnect current;" but still the message is shown when i try to connect.

I made a "show connections;" to see if there're another "instances" but it says "No connections available".

So tell me how to solve this problem, what can I try to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

The problem was solved by deleting the files with extension *.lck from the directory where the DB lives. I deleted the temp directory too but I'm not sure if this was part of the solution.

Comment: OH! Please be VERY VERY careful when you do this! Those lock files are there for a reason! Hopefully you haven't just corrupted your database. I think what is going on is that your other copy of `ij` was still actually running, even though you thought you had exited it.